# How to wait for action and API call to complete using redux saga?

Tags: reactjs, redux-saga

I am dispatching an action which makes an API call to a backend and then I am updating the store. I need to access props on the next line after the action dispatch in my React Component.

```
this.props.getUser();

//need the user here
console.log(this.props);
```

Action looks like this in my actions.js file and is being mapped to props in my react component

```
const getUser = () => ({
  type: 'GET_USER'
});
```

The action goes into the Saga.js file which calls a service file with the API call. If this is not sufficient information please let me know and I will elaborate more on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `redux-saga`, `yield` is the keyword that waits for the API call to finish, and returns our results. The basic pattern of using it for API calls looks like this:

```
import { call, put, takeEvery, takeLatest } from 'redux-saga/effects'
import Api from '...' <-- the path to your API endpoint

// will be fired on GET_USER actions
function* getUser(action) {
   try {
      // redux-saga will wait till the endpoint function will finish and return
      const user = yield call(Api.getUser);
      // In your reducer: you're returning the user 
      yield put({type: "GET_USER_SUCCEEDED", user: user});
   } catch (e) {
      // Or an error message 
      yield put({type: "GET_USER_FAILED", message: e.message});
   }
}

// the saga you link to your middle-ware setup where you setting up the store.
function* rootSaga() {
  yield takeEvery("GET_USER", getUser);
}
```

Note that you'll want `redux` to handle request/error/success. then you'll need the following cases `GET_USER`, `GET_USER_FAILED` & `GET_USER_SUCCEEDED`, respectively.